# World Bank WBDATA on Anaconda3 and pip uninstall/install is throwing a cache directory error

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\wbdata\\wbdata\\Cache'
```

I run Anaconda3 and my virtualenv lost that ability to run wbdata. After reinstalling the World Bank wbdata  0.3.0 script, it's throwing the error above on my Windows development machine

The real problem is that Python doesn't always alert that the Cache file conflict is the problem. This leaves the programmer to wonder why the script has simply stopped running.

I find that my mix of interwoven flask apps and python background scripts (I use "popen") confuses the wbdata cache into recognizing a cache permissions issue.

It might be that `popen` is not also activating my virtual python environment - so that a virtual env and conda's native env are now competing for the same wbdata cache directory?

I suspected initially that this cache conflict could also be (could be = not certain) a result of installing Conda first and then having to rely on "`PIP install`" for libraries that Conda does offer. I don't think conda supports the installation of wbdata - for one example.

I have two "Lib" directories on my installations on Windows 8.1. This probably appears normal, but sometimes python is looking into a different Lib directory for background run scripts - and sometimes not (maybe a popen issue where it's not activating my virtual env?):

1. `\users\name\Anaconda3\envs\envname\Lib`
2. `\users\name\Anaconda3\Lib`

To solve the problem, I have added full access permissions to all users on this Windows 8.1 OS for the cache directory. That doesn't seem to solve the problem - although it does *seem?* to reduce the rate of occurrence to "very infrequent".

I tried:

1. (re)installing with:

   `conda install -c anaconda wbdata`

No WBDATA was found

I also ran a `conda uninstall wbdata` just in case ...

2. `pip install wbdata`

This installed wbdata without error until I ran wbdata to collect api info

3. `pip uninstall wbdata` ; `pip install wbdata`

Reinstalling in this way with `pip` didn't eliminate the problem.

I looked at online documentation and can't find a similar error.

Questions are:

1. What is the best best-practice method of cleaning up this inconsistency between Anaconda3 `conda` and `PIP` installed wbdata caches?
2. Does `popen` need to be instructed which virtual env to open - to prevent this python cache conflict - and, if this is an obvious problem that never previously occurred to me, then what would that `popen` command look like?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out after a lot of research that WBDATA caches are simply files that can be deleted in Windows using a file explorer or any other method. Once the file is removed WBDATA resumed to full functionality ...

My cache directory (on a Windows 8.1 development windows PC) is `C:\\Users\\USERID\\AppData\\Local\\wbdata\\wbdata\\cache`

I delete this cache and all returns to normal.
As for the cause of this problem, it might/probably/absolutely has to do with how you are invoking Python.exe; each ENV has its own python.exe that you should be running, so if you are running the generic base python.exe, you could create a conflict as the two apps compete for the same cache directory.
Hope this helps

Comment: It does and that's true, but python doesn't always alert that the Cache was the problem. This leaves the programmer to wonder where the problem is coming from.
I find that a mix of interwoven flask and python background scripts confuses the cache python into recognizing a cache permissions issue. 
I have added full access permissions to all in the windows OS for the cache directory but that doesn't seem to solve the problem - although it has reduced its rate of occurence.

Comment: how do you remove the caches? where are they?

Comment: cache directory location depends on where you installed your Conda or Wbdata but for me it is located at C:\\Users\\USERID\\AppData\\Local\\wbdata\\wbdata\\cache
Just delete this cache directory ... and I suggest that you look to ensure that you are invoking python.exe correctly - as this could be the source of your problem. Each ENV should have a python.exe for you to use only.

Answer (score 0):

I run Anaconda,too. It works if you install it with

```
pip install -U wbdata
```

Check the details here
https://wbdata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/